# Communicate with the android RIL daemon or Intercept Messages from the RIL android daemon

Tags: android, android-ndk, ril

Is it possible to communicate with the android RIL daemon using the android NDK ? I would like to get *notifications* from the RIL daemon or better i would like to grab the messages which are sent to the upper *Aplication Framework* and modify/filter them and after that transmit them to the upper layer.

I know there is a **shared rilib** and I know i can use it and access it functions using dlopen / dlsym ..but i have no idea if that would help me or not :)

Note: What i want to do is to filter messages from the RIL deamon about incoming calls from unvanted numbers (call blocking)

Also do you know any way (trick) how could I do call handling / call blocking in native code using android-ndk and the available libs ???

As always thanks for all your replies...

Answer (score 3):

Unless someone made a mistake, you should not be able to disrupt critical device functionality from an application, even in native code.

Android does not right now have a mechanism for a user to decide to trust an application to do something that would be overwhelmingly disruptive if done wrong.  Practically speaking if you want to do this you root your phone and start making your own modified version of android.